# Including Protobufs with Bazel

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, bazel

I have the following `BUILD` file:

```
load("@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf.bzl", "cc_proto_library")

### Protos ###

cc_proto_library(
    name = "homework_cc_proto",
    protoc = "@com_google_protobuf//:protoc",
    default_runtime = "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf",
)

proto_library(
    name = "homework_proto",
    srcs = [
        "protos/complexity.proto",
        "protos/example.proto",
        "protos/problem.proto",
        "protos/solution.proto",
    ],
)

### End Protos ###

### Binaries ###

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [":homework_cc_proto"],
)
```

and `main.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "example.pb.h"

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

If I invoke `bazel build :homework_cc_proto`, the build is successful. However, when I run `bazel build :main` I get an error saying that `example.pb.h` cannot be found. How can I import my built protobufs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cc_proto_library` needs to depend on `homework_proto`.

```
cc_proto_library(
    name = "homework_cc_proto",
    protoc = "@com_google_protobuf//:protoc",
    default_runtime = "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf",
    deps = [ ":homework_proto" ],
)
```